# react native "Build failed with an exception"

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:
  Build file 'C:\Users\ertu\Desktop\r\a\android\app\build.gradle' line: 1
- What went wrong:
  A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

> Failed to apply plugin 'com.android.internal.application'.
> Android Gradle plugin requires Java 11 to run. You are currently using Java 1.8.
> You can try some of the following options:
> - changing the IDE settings.
> - changing the JAVA_HOME environment variable.
> - changing `org.gradle.java.home` in `gradle.properties`.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CjAER.png

Answer (score 0):

The latest version of react native requires JDK 11.

First, check which version of JDK is installed in your system. In your system terminal whatever OS you are using

```
java --version
```

if the java version is less than 11 then uninstall the JDK from your system and then install JDK 11. [Click here to get the JDK 11](https://www.oracle.com/java/technologies/javase/jdk11-archive-downloads.html)

Comment: I've java 11 installed but still get the above error. You can see java version below output of java  --version command.                                                                                                     
       java 11.0.16 2022-07-19 LTS                                                                                             Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.16+11-LTS-199)                                                         Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM 18.9 (build 11.0.16+11-LTS-199, mixed mode)